# C# cast assembly class to type

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

Is there any way to cast a class from an external (managed) assembly to a specific interface?

I mean instead of calling `MethodInfo.Invoke(instance, parameters);` , do something like this

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyName);
System.Type type = assembly.GetType(typeName);
Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
IYourType yourObj = (o as IYourType);
```

**UPDATE**

I have an external assembly with a known interface and yes I have a local copy of the one referenced in the assembly. The inspection shows that o is of type assembly.GetType(typeName);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# cast reflected object to interface returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041015/c-sharp-cast-reflected-object-to-interface-returns-null)

Comment: The post you are referring to is marked as off-topic

Comment: You were asked in your last question to give clarification, i think its curious you would ask the same question with none of the clarifications and expect different answers. There is no question here, it cant be solve, any answer is just a guess

Comment: You cannot cast a **class**, you can only cast an **object**.

Comment: @TheGeneral I 've made clarifications but the post is still marked offtopic, so I have rephrased the question.

Comment: @dymanoid o is an object in my example

Comment: In your question, you ask: "is there any way to cast a class from..." So the answer is: no, you cannot cast a class.

Comment: You can cast object to its' real type and to those which it inherits from. You can't cast Potato to Car. : )

Comment: Ok ill ask them all again. Have you debugged this, What is the type of `o` when you inspect it. Is this interface a local copy of the one referenced in the assembly, does `typeof(IYourType)type.IsAssignableFrom(type)` work. Does `o` even implement an interface, how do you know this, where does it come from.

Comment: At this point we just cant work this out for you, there is not enough information for us.

Comment: I'm guessing maybe OP is looking for something like [Castle DynamicProxy](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/docs/dynamicproxy.md)???

Comment: @TheGeneral  I have an external assembly with a known interface and yes I have a local copy of the one referenced in the assembly. The inspection shows that o is of type assembly.GetType(typeName);

Comment: @DevelopeCruz ok we are getting somewhere, are both this code and your assembly pointing to exactly the same interface. is it in a shared library? if not you can never cast it

Comment: @TheGeneral hmm, so If I have an Interface in a shared library, I would be able to cast it. I will give it a try, thanks !

Comment: @TheGeneral Worked like a charm! Can you post this as an answer please? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you have created a local copy of that interface your reflected class uses.

This just won't work, the Jitter knows enough about the both interfaces to know they aren't the same, it returns null.

Interfaces are contracts between two entities. What you are effectively trying to do is dupe .Net into think thinking it has the same contract, in short it won't be duped.

Since there is no point in reflecting the interface from the assembly (as you can't use it at design time), the only option available is make that interface shared between the two assemblies. This is how plug-in systems work. They know enough about each other to communicate through interfaces.